# Probability of at least 6 out of 10

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

i have the following question:
In an exam, 10 questions are chosen randomly from 100.
A student is prepared for 60 out 100 of these questions.
What's the probability that he'll solve at least 6 questions out of the chosen 10?
I'm a bit confused as to what the probability plain and the events are.
Do i say that $|\Omega| = {100\choose10} $, and the event $A=$"at least 6 of the 10 questions are among the students' 60 " ?

Comment: Yes, see this link on the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: I don't see the connection, sorry.

Comment: Separate the $100$ questions into the $60$  the student's prepared for and the $40$ he hasn't, then there are $\binom{100}{10}$ possible question sets. Out of these there are $\binom{60}{6}\binom{40}{4}$ ways that $6$ will be from the $60$ and $4$ will be from the $40$, thus the probability that the student will solve exactly $6$ questions is $$\frac{\binom{60}{6}\binom{40}{4}}{\binom{100}{10}}$$ assuming he solves every question he has prepared for. Similarly the probability that he has prepared for exactly $7$ questions is  $$\frac{\binom{60}{7}\binom{40}{3}}{\binom{100}{10}} $$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of probability problems can be solved by reframing the question in the context of balls and urns. In this case, the *hypergeometric distribution* is pertinent as the following excerpt from Blitzstein shows:

> Consider an urn with $w$ white balls and $b$ black balls. We draw $n$ balls out of the urn at random without replacement, such that all ${w+b \choose n}$ samples are equally likely. Let $X$ be the number of white balls in the sample. Then $X$ is said to have the Hypergeometric distribution with parameters $w$, $b$, and $n$; we denote this by $X \sim \text{HGeom}(w,b,n)$.

For your problem, $n$ is the number of questions are chosen randomly, $w$ is the number of questions that the student is prepared for, $b$ is the number of questions he is not prepared for,
and $X$ is the number of correct answers on the student's exam.

Now that you have properly modeled the problem, all you have to do is calculate

$$P(\text{at least 6 out of 10}) = P(X \geq 6), $$
with the [appropriate pmf](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Answer (score 0):

A permutational approach - Equivalence of permutation and combination formula

Define event A to be there are at least 6 successes out of n = 10
trials. Let's also use symbols: "s" for success, "f" for failure, "t"
for trial" "Pr" for probability, "P" for permutation and "C" for
combination,
"P(n, r)" for selecting r out of n objects in permutation and C(n, r)
for select r out of n objects in combination.

Exactly 6 s out of 10 t, assume first 6 are s, last 4 are f "in that order".

Pr($A_6$, po) = 60/100 * 59/99 * 58/98 * .../55/95 * 40/94 * 39/93 * ..* 37/91
= P (60, 6)* P(40, 4)/ P(100, 10)

But there are C (10, 6) = P(10, 6)/ 6! = I such possibilities.

So exactly 6 s out of 10 t "in any order" is

Pr ($A_6$) = $\sum_{ i =1}^I$Pr ($A_6$, po) = I * Pr($A_6$, po)
= C(10, 6) * P(60, 6) * P(40, 4) / P(100, 10)
= C(10, 6) * (6!* 4! /10!) *C(60, 6) * C(40, 4) / C(100,10)
= C(10, 6)/C(10,6) * C(60, 6) * C(40, 4) / C(100,10)
= C(60, 6) * C(40, 4) / C(100,10),
which is exactly the results using combination approach!

The probability of solving at least 6 s out of 10 t is
Pr(A) = $\sum_{i=6}^{10}$ Pr($A_i$).

Comment: This solution assumes independence of selection.  But as (presumably) a given question won't be selected more than once, we wouldn't have independence.

Comment: Thanks, you have a very good point! Instead of p^ k, do I need p1= P- i 1)/(N-I+))

Comment: Sorry, this is unclear to me.

Comment: I will have to come back at a later time to post an update.  Sorry, my post was incomplete as I hit a return button by mistake.  When I tried to correct it, I was told to wait until  at least tomorrow as I have used my daily quota which is one post a day. I am a newbie, so some restrictions applied. Stay tuned.

Comment: I am still not allowed to post.